# How do i enable memory overcommit on solaris?

Tags: memory, solaris, swap

on a solaris 8 server with a specific workload, how do i turn on memory overcommit (à la Linux) ?

```
# Memory size: 65536 Megabytes
sun[root] # vmstat 1
procs     memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr m0 m1 m1 m1   in   sy   cs us sy id
0 0 0 30679520 38600344 123 318 941 0 0 0 0 4 0  3  0 7640 11016 7196 5  2 93

sun[root] # swap -s
total: 18808072k bytes allocated + 48426552k reserved = 67234624k used, 972480k available

sun[root] # swap -l
swapfile             dev  swaplo blocks   free
/dev/md/dsk/d1      85,1      16 33560432 33556592
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Solaris is not supporting memory overcommit with the normal `malloc()` function but with `mmap(MAP_NORESERVE)`. There is a nice newsgroup article about that including a link to the official Sun source. http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2008-03/msg00687.html